# Logging log4j message into database

Tags: java, sql-server, logging

Hi I am developing an application which requires logging the log message into database. I used the EnhancedPattenrLayout in log4j properties file to log the message into DB. But I am getting error logging the exception stack trace into db stating that

> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary
>   data would be truncated."

Note that intentionally I've given the wrong smtp to check whether it logging the exception stack trace into DB or not.

please help me in this regards.

> Here find log4j.properties file

```
 # Define the root logger with file appender
log4j.rootLogger = debug, sql, stdout
#log4j.rootLogger = error, sql, stdout

# Log for the Hibernate
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate=INFO
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=trace
#log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=ALL

# ================ Added as part of logging into DB ====================
# Define the jdbc appender
log4j.appender.sql=org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender
log4j.appender.sql.URL=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=ERP_IDMS

# Set Database Driver
log4j.appender.sql.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

# Set database user name and password
log4j.appender.sql.user=ERP_ADMIN_IDMS
log4j.appender.sql.password=Password

# Set the SQL statement to be executed.
#short
log4j.appender.sql.layout.ConversionPattern=INSERT INTO LOGS1 VALUES ('%d{yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss.SSS}' ,'%C','%p','%m', '%throwable{short}', '%throwable{800}')
# Define the xml layout for file appender
log4j.appender.sql.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
#=======================================================================

# Direct to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# =============================================================================
```

> Table script

```
    USE [ERP_IDMS]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [ERP_ADMIN].[LOGS1]    Script Date: 01/18/2016 16:55:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [ERP_ADMIN].[LOGS1](
    [DATED] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LOGGER] [varchar](500) NOT NULL,
    [LEVEL] [varchar](200) NOT NULL,
    [MESSAGE] [varchar](1500) NOT NULL,
    [THROWABLE] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [STACKTRACE] [varchar](5000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
```

> Java file

```
    package erp.idms.test;

import java.util.Date;
//import java.util.HashMap;
//import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
//import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


import com.erp.idms.mail.exception.EMailException;
import com.erp.idms.mail.exception.SMTPNotFoundException;



/*import erp.idms.mail.exception.*;
import erp.idms.mail.vo.EmailServiceRequestVO;
import erp.idms.mail.vo.EmailServiceResponseVO;
import erp.idms.modal.MailingList;
import erp.idms.test.MailTest;*/

public class MailTest {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MailTest.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MailTest test = new MailTest();
        try {
            test.sendMail("Hi \n this is a test mail");
        } catch (EMailException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMail(String msg) throws EMailException {

        Transport transport = null;
        String transportStr = "smtp";
        String contentStr = "text/plain";
        String smtpHostStr = "mail.smtp.host";

        String smtpHost = "192.85.144.90";

        final String username = "raghav-ku@hp.com";// change accordingly
        final String password = "tunn@123";// change accordingly
        String responseStatus = null;
        String message_header = null;
        String message_footer = null;

        // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
        String to = "mukesh-kumarp@hpe.com";//anil.veldandi@hp.com



        String from = "mcbc_apc_dataload@yxls.com";
        String from1 = "rahr-kumarp@syhla.com";

        Session session = null;

        try {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            if (username != null) {
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            }
            props.put(smtpHostStr, smtpHost);

            // Get the Session object.
            session = Session.getInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username,
                                    password);
                        }
                    });
            session.setDebug(false);
            // Create a default MimeMessage object.
            MimeMessage mimeMsg = new MimeMessage(session);

            // Set From: header field of the header.
            mimeMsg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

            // Set To: header field of the header.
            mimeMsg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(to));
            // Setting the "CC recipients" addresses if exists
            String ccAddress = null;
            if (ccAddress != null && !"".equals(ccAddress)) {
                mimeMsg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAddress);
            }

            // Set Subject: header field
            mimeMsg.setSubject("Testing Subject");

            // Create the message part
            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Now set the actual message
            mimeBodyPart.setText(msg);

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(mimeBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            //mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String[] fileToBeAttached = new String[3];
            fileToBeAttached = null;
            //fileToBeAttached[0] = "C:\\ERP_Automation\\OutBoundDir\\outBound.csv";
            //fileToBeAttached[1] = "C:\\IDMS_ERP_DataAutomation\\Invoice.log";
            //fileToBeAttached[2] = "C:\\IDMS_ERP_DataAutomation\\Invoice.bad";

            if (fileToBeAttached != null && fileToBeAttached.length > 0) {

                for (String filenameAttach : fileToBeAttached) {
                    MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filenameAttach);
                    attachPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                    String fileName = filenameAttach
                            .substring(filenameAttach.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
                    // mimeBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                    attachPart.setFileName(fileName);

                    // Send the complete message parts
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);

                }

            }


            mimeMsg.setContent(multipart);
            // Set the Date: header
            mimeMsg.setSentDate(new Date());

            mimeMsg.saveChanges();

            // Send message
            // Transport.send(mimeMsg);

            transport = session.getTransport(transportStr);
            System.out.println("----connecting Transport ----");
            logger.info("----connecting Transport ----");
            transport.connect();
            System.out.println(mimeMsg.getAllRecipients());
            transport.sendMessage(mimeMsg, mimeMsg.getAllRecipients());

            System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
            logger.info("Sent message successfully....");

        }/* catch (MessagingException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Exception while sending the Message"+e);
            throw new SMTPNotFoundException("Unable to send the Mail", e);
        }*/ catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Exception while sending the Message",e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }




    private static class SMTPAuth extends Authenticator {
        private String user;
        private String pass;

        /**
         * @param u
         * @param p
         */
        public SMTPAuth(String username, String password) {
            user = username;
            pass = password;
        }

        /* (non-Javadoc)
         * @see javax.mail.Authenticator#getPasswordAuthentication()
         */
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass);
        }
    }



}
```

full exception stack trace

```
    ----connecting Transport ----
d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} INFO  MailTest:165 - ----connecting Transport ----
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.85.144.90, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1008)
d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} ERROR MailTest:179 - Exception while sending the Message
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.85.144.90, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1008)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:104)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.sendMail(MailTest.java:166)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.main(MailTest.java:45)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:104)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.sendMail(MailTest.java:166)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.main(MailTest.java:45)
log4j:ERROR Failed to excute sql
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:254)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:84)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1517)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:799)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:1716)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:180)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:155)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:649)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.execute(JDBCAppender.java:178)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.flushBuffer(JDBCAppender.java:250)
    at org.apache.log4j.jdbc.JDBCAppender.append(JDBCAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:230)
    at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:65)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:203)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:388)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.error(Category.java:319)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.sendMail(MailTest.java:179)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.main(MailTest.java:45)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.85.144.90, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.sendMail(MailTest.java:180)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.main(MailTest.java:45)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.85.144.90, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1008)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:197)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:86)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:104)
    at erp.idms.test.MailTest.sendMail(MailTest.java:166)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Can you post all stacktrace?

Comment: You have also a Connection error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your columns are too small to hold the data to be logged, so instead of truncating the data it throws an exception. Find out which column is the problem and make it bigger.

Comment: Hi Kayaman your are right, I got the issue and increased the length of THROWABLE column of the LOGS1 table.

Answer (score 0):

I got the issue and increased the length of THROWABLE column of the LOGS1 table.